# Gridview editing without postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Gridview with Edit option. When i click on Edit button row becomes editable with Update & cancel button. But this process causes a postback which degrades performance in my scenario. Is there any other way available to make row editable without causing a postback(maybe using javascript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net has this handy feature built in. Its called an update panel and it allows you to specify part of a page to update. It uses ajax to perform a behind the scenes postback.

Here is an article on the subject by [4 Guys from Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102853/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102407-1.aspx)  which contains some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from javascript too. two options:

1. Using pageMethod call a method inside code behind with required parameters.
2. Expose a web service and set the DB update function there and call the function from javascript.

Using update panel may cause certain issues...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the issues are with the updatepanel approach?